# T-SQL Split Update Statement Into Parallel Chunks

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, parallel-processing

I have a process which builds out a tree type structure in a table. Then once the tree is built an update statement runs to update 1 column in the table based on other columns in the table (that were created during the tree creation part of the procedure). So there is no joining to other tables in the update. Everything can be done on a row by row basis within the table. Example of the table (before the update) is below.

```
DrillPath    TimePeriod    CellValue
1            1             NULL
1,2          1             NULL
1,3          1             NULL
1            2             NULL
1,2          2             NULL
1,3          2             NULL
```

So the update statement looks something like this.

```
update table set CellValue = dbo.SomeLongRunningFunction(DrillPath, TimePeriod)
```

Function `dbo.SomeLongRunningFunction()` tables about 5 milliseconds to run for each call and we are calling it hundreds of thousands of times (that's how many rows exist in the table). It used to take about 90ms so we have already greatly improved the performance of the function. The function is rather complex in nature but I am abstracting away the complexity in this example. Example of table after the update.

```
DrillPath    TimePeriod    CellValue
1            1             5.1
1,2          1             3.2
1,3          1             NULL (NULL can be a valid answer)
1            2             1.0
1,2          2             2.5
1,3          2             8.1
```

I would like to "chunk" this update into 5 (or in the general case `x` parallel updates) each operating on a subset of the rows. The `with (rowlock)` hint perhaps could be used to ensure no deadlocks occur as each "chunk" will be updating it's own rows and "chunks" will never intersect.

My first go-to application was SSIS and running a stored procedure 5 times in parallel and passing in the low/high ranges to be updated. However it appears only 1 procedure is actually updating at any given time while the others are waiting. Which leads me to believe the update statement is locking the full table even though `with (rowlock)` is being used for the update. I know only 1 is running because I can select from the table in a query window and see how many records have been updated. And the number of records is not increasing at the rate I would expect to see if I split the work across 5 processes.

I am seeking any other methodologies and suggestions on how to run these updates in parallel. I need to stay within the confines of "out of the box" SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition in an secure environment (no xp_cmdshell, maybe a CLR function or custom assembly if there is no other option). I have SSIS as an option as well.

Any thoughts?

Comment: How exactly did you split up the update? Did you use PK ranges or something else?

Comment: I have not found very many (if any) problems where the logic encapsulated within a UDF can't be made set based, then if re-usability is an issue it be added to a view (so you can join to the view rather than execute a function). I think the best solution will be to pick apart your UDF and try and do the update faster, rather than trying to do more updates at once.

Comment: The update is split on a RowNumber column which is part of the PK. I have a proc that chunks out the rows into groups (1-100, 101-200, 201-300, etc.) and then the update procedure accepts a low and high range and the update statement has a where clause that limits the records.

Comment: Hi GarethD. We have attempted set based calculations instead of the function without success. The logic in the function is simply too complex. I always work toward a set based approach but in this case the UDF is required.

Answer (score 0):

So I actually decided to just use a table variable in the procedure which runs the update.

```
Step 1: insert into the table variable the "chunk" from the real table that I want to update.
Step 2: update the column in the table variable.
Step 3: delete the "chunk" from the real table.
Step 4: insert the table variable rows into the real table.
```

This eliminates any issues with locking and my chunks are not large enough to really cause any concern around memory utilization.

I was able to run the procedure in parallel in SSIS and saw the run time decrease proportionally to the number of chunks I used.